# How to slide a block on a plane in inventor and at the end rotate it over the edge

Tags: autodesk-inventor

In Autodesk Inventor I wanna slide a cubus over a rectangular plane. When the cubus touch the edge it need to rotate over de edge. See image for better understanding.[image]

Comment: what have you tried?  ... what was the result?

Comment: Tried a constraint to slide the block over the rectangular plate and than another to turn it over the edge. But than the cubus wil lock itself in position like on the image. I had this problem serveral times with inventor. I just want a constrain to a certain point and than another takes it over.

Comment: In SW you would use a path mate, with a fitspline to make a single continuous entity as the path around the corner - it effectively will have a very very small radius at the corner. Maybe inventor has an equivalent?